# python local module with same

Tags: python, python-import

I have a local python code repo like the following. 
In `python/foo/code.py` I want to import `target_module` in `foo/bar/baz/target_module`. However, because `code.py` is under the `foo` module, I cannot import `target_module`. Since it's a largish repo with a great deal of legacy code, I cannot easily change any directory name. Is there any other workaround?

Thanks in advance!

```
|──foo
|   ├──bar
|         ├──baz
|               ├── target_module
├── python
|   ├── foo
|   │   ├── code.py      <----from foo.bar.baz.target_module import *
```

Comment: checkout [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Comment: You shouldn't be having this problem if you're using python 3

Comment: @MadPhysicist The OP would have the problem if it's not really a python package (.e. no `__init__.py`s) and it's just a bunch of directories with some python scripts. All bets are off in legacy

Answer (score 1):

There a couple ways you can do this. The quick and dirty is to just add it to your interpreter's path.

Here's my setup:

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro:test_project matt$ tree
.
├── foo
│   └── bar
│       └── baz
│           └── target_module.py
└── python
    └── foo
        └── code.py

5 directories, 2 files
```

Here's the contents of `target_module.py`:

```
def my_func():
    print("my func called.")
```

and how you can import this function into `code.py`:

```
import os
import sys

# Cheat and just add it to python interpreter's path                                                                                                                                                        
this_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(this_dir, "..", "..", "foo", "bar", "baz"))

import target_module as tm
tm.my_func()
```

this outputs:

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro:test_project matt$ python python/foo/code.py 
my func called.
```

or you can call it from the `foo` directory and it'll still work fine:

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro:test_project matt$ cd python/foo/
Matthews-MacBook-Pro:foo matt$ python code.py 
my func called.
```

You can also just add the `foo/bar/baz` directory to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable instead of calling `sys.path.append`. This syntax is shell dependent: so I'll let you google how to set environment variables for your particular shell.

**Ideally you'd want to make your modules deployable** (i.e. use `setup.py` and `distutils` or `setuptools` and put `__init__.py` in each module), and then you can import "normally" (kind of like you can "just" `import numpy` and it works). **But since you claim it's legacy, maybe this might be hard for you to accomplish. I get it: in legacy systems all bets are off and sometimes the quick and dirty is fine (and maybe even ideal if you don't want to spend a lot of time fixing the issue).**

I can expand this answer if you're interested in creating deployable python packages, and if not, the above should get the job done.

HTH.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you so much for your solution. As you said, this quick method does work. However, i do need the method to make the code deployable. The reason I mentioned legacy is that there are many people working on this repo and there're are reasons I cannot change the dir name with reasonable efforts. It would be great if you can share the method that can create deployable package. Thanks!!